# How to get information about usage of other apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, permissions, usage-statistics

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the amount of time user spends a day on YouTube app or any data really about user's app usage.

Reading this [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212025#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Privacy%20settings%20to,track%20for%20a%20specific%20app.) from Apple I can assume that the only use I have asking for [NSUserTrackingUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsusertrackingusagedescription) would be for personal advertisements.

My question is if I'm suppose to ask this permission in order to get stats about user's app usage and if there's another way to get this information(if it's even possible).

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Not even searching for currently active applications? For instance If I would like to know if user launched YouTube app at some specific time?

Comment: Nope. It would be a privacy violation. What the user is doing is none of your app's business.  This isn't a permission that your app can ask for. Apple already provides Screentime in the os if the user wants to monitor or limit their usage of apps.

Comment: Paulw11 I greatly appreciate your answer, thank you!